# on change same value of input type text but different id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I create a table with looping rows it has 3 column  with input type text
3 input fields, give the 2 & 3 input field always the same value as input field one
check it out if my code is correct?
*Demo*: https://jsfiddle.net/Ninay/cpk15a98/

```
 $('#thelist[' + counter +'].DocDT').change(function() {
for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
  $('#thelist[' + i +  '].StartDT ,#thelist[' + i + '].EndDT').val($(this).val());
              }});
```

Comment: You just need to escape metacharacters (i.e., dots, semicolons, square brackets...)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a dot `.` when setting element id?

- `id="thelist[' + counter +'].StartDT"`

`#thelist[' + counter +  '].DocDT` this selector mean your target html element have:

- id is `thelist[' + counter +  ']`
- class is `DocDT`

You must use another character to replace dot `.` ex: `_`

I suggest you use class selector for this problem, with class selector you can setting `change` event without `.each' loop.

I had change this demo pls check that! hope this can help you!
https://jsfiddle.net/cpk15a98/6/